# Append the block before some keyword

Tags: ansible

I'm using below code to append one file content to another file and it is suppossed to be inserted before the `#[SWC]` string only but it is getting written over at any other place in the file. Can anyone suggest something on it?

```yaml
- name: Adding {{ MKT }} subprofile in Rhel master profile
  tags: merge
  blockinfile:
    path: /tools/Migration/TWS/Release/Profiles/profile
    block: "{{lookup('file', '/tools/PMX_Migration/TWS/Release/Profiles/{{MKT}}.subprofile.txt')}}"
    insertbefore: "#[SWC]"
    backup: yes
    create: true
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
```

I tried replacing the commented lines with any other string that hasn't be commented but it didn't work.

Comment: Post minimal example of the files *profile* and *subprofile.txt*, and post the expected result. [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Remove all details that are not relevant to repeat the problem: complex paths, tags, run_once, delegate_to, backup. Focus on what's important: path, block, insertbefore. Remove the variable *MKT*.

Answer (score 1):

- The square brackets `[ ]` have a special meaning in [Python regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Quote:

> [ ] Used to indicate a set of characters ...

You have to escape the square brackets `[]` in a regular expression if you want to indicate the square brackets as characters `[` and `]`

```yaml
        insertbefore: '#\[SWC\]'
```

The regex will match any of the characters in the set if you don't escape the brackets (*#S, #W, #C*). You can [test it online](https://pythex.org/).

```yaml
        insertbefore: '#[SWC]'
```

- If you use the [single-quoted style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style) a single backslash `\` will do the job. Quote:

> The single-quoted style is specified by surrounding `'` indicators. Therefore, within a single-quoted scalar, such characters need to be repeated. This is the only form of escaping performed in single-quoted scalars. In particular, the `\` and `"` characters may be freely used. This restricts single-quoted scalars to printable characters.

```yaml
        insertbefore: '#\[SWC\]'
```

- If you use the [double-quoted style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#731-double-quoted-style) a backslash must be escaped too `\\`. Quote:

> The double-quoted style is specified by surrounding `"` indicators. This is the only style capable of expressing arbitrary strings, by using `\` escape sequences. This comes at the cost of having to escape the `\` and `"` characters.

```yaml
        insertbefore: "#\\[SWC\\]"
```

- Test it. Given the files

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/profile.txt
A
B
C
#[SWC]
X
Y
Z
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/subprofile.txt
subprofile_1
subprofile_2
```

The play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - blockinfile:
        path: /tmp/profile.txt
        block: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/subprofile.txt') }}"
        insertbefore: '#\[SWC\]'
```

running in *check* and *diff* mode shows the difference

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -CD
  ...
TASK [blockinfile] ****************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/profile.txt (content)
+++ after: /tmp/profile.txt (content)
@@ -1,6 +1,9 @@
 A
 B
 C
+# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
+subprofile_1
+subprofile_2
+# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
 #[SWC]
 X
 Y

changed: [localhost]
```

Comment: But my data is still getting at the end of file only :(

Comment: It's difficult to believe. What is preventing you from posting [mre] in the question?